# trouble generating smoothing splines over scatterplot data in R

Tags: r, spline

Trying to generate smoothing splines over some bone density data and having a bit of trouble. Essentially copied the example from my statistical learning textbook and tried to modify some of the code to fit, but don't really understand exactly what's going on with it or why it's not working.

Would be ideal to generate two fitted lines for the male and female data in the same plot.

Here's my code so far:

```
bone <- read.csv('/Users/myname/Desktop/ML Extra Credit/spnbmd.csv')
library(splines)

plot(spnbmd ~ age, data=bone, col = 
       ifelse(sex=="mal", "blue","red"),
       xlab="Age", ylab="Relative Change in Spinal BMD")
legend("topleft",
       c("male","female"),
       fill=c("blue","red")
)


fit=lm(spnbmd~bs(age,knots=c(10,15,20)),data=bone)
pred=predict(fit,newdata=list(age=age.grid),se=T)
plot(age,wage,col="gray")
lines(age.grid,pred$fit,lwd=2)
lines(age.grid,pred$fit+2*pred$se ,lty="dashed")
lines(age.grid,pred$fit-2*pred$se ,lty="dashed")
```

[image: scatterplot]

https://github.com/khammerberg53/MLEC/blob/main/spnbmd.csv

link to data ^

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You code uses the variable `age.grid` but that's not defined anywhere. Please make sure to define all values in your example.

Comment: I suspected that was part of the problem, but I am fairly clueless when it comes to this stuff so I wasn't sure how to properly define it.

Comment: Well, that's really up to you, one possibility is `age.grid <- seq(10,25, by=.5)`

Comment: I'm able to fit a spline over all the data with your help but I was wondering if I could fit two separate splines for the male and female data on the same scatterplot.

Comment: You'd have to fit the model once per group. It's possible with base R but it's a bit of work. An easier way would be to use `ggplot2`: `ggplot(bone) + aes(age, spnbmd, color=sex)  + geom_point() + geom_smooth(formula = y~bs(x, knots=c(10,15,20)), method="lm")`. That would do everything.

Comment: Wow. Yeah, this is great. Excited to dig into tidyverse a bit more.